# My SSL certificate says it is issued to instance name of my VM

Tags: openssl, google-cloud-platform, apache2, ssl-certificate

This is my website: https://edusys.ml

[image]

It should be showing Issued to edusys.ml

Comment: Did you add a custom SSL domain in the Google App Engine console? `App Engine -> Settings -> Custom Domains`

Comment: No, I haven't .

Comment: I got my website secured with SSL by following [this document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/mapping-custom-domains#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application). In short, you first add a TXT DNS record to confirm your ownership of your domain, then update A, AAAA, and CNAME records to have you domain point to your appspot with SSL secured.

Comment: Thank you. It has led to a complication, but I am sure I can fix it.

Comment: @JagannathBhat Did you get this issue resolved? If so, can you post the resolution as an answer, and then 48 hours later can you mark it as accepted? If not, can you let us know where things stand?

Comment: I din't resolve it that way.  
I had secured my website using the instructions from [this site](https://www.sslforfree.com/). And it lead to this error.  

I tried @DavidChen 's method but it din't work for me.  

So I used [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) instead. That worked.

Comment: @JagannathBhat Can you post your solution as an answer on your own question, then accept it? (There might be a 48 hour delay before you can accept it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL certificate generated here was from [sslforfree.com](https://www.sslforfree.com/). Instead the [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) can be used. Go to [this link](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) for full instructions on how to generate an SSL certificate for free.